# Show SharePoint Hover panel on another page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I want to show the hover panel on a page that is **NOT** the search page. I have a div as shown below:
[image]

I want it so that when I hover over the box, it shows the hover panel. I have been using Inspect Element on the search page to see how it has been implemented but I dont know how to make it work.

Comment: Search is using display template to show the hover function. Look into bootstraps popovers. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: How can I use the display template for other things?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into **Callout.js**. This contains the **CalloutManager** class which handles callouts/hover panels within SharePoint.

If you would like to try this out, use a Script Editor web part on a SharePoint page and copy paste the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CreateCallOutPopup, "callout.js");
function CreateCallOutPopup()
{
var targetElement = document.getElementById('NotificationDiv');
// configure options
var calloutOptions = new CalloutOptions();
calloutOptions.ID = 'notificationcallout';
calloutOptions.launchPoint = targetElement;
calloutOptions.beakOrientation = 'leftRight';
calloutOptions.content = 'content';
calloutOptions.title = 'title';
var callout = CalloutManager.createNew(calloutOptions);
}
</script>

<div id="NotificationDiv" style="width:50px;"><span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">&#160;</span> </div>
```

Save and Publish the page and you will see the Callout.js in action.

[image]

Here is some detailed information on the callout classes and attributes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/highlight-content-and-enhance-the-functionality-of-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint